# Why ever use set errexit instead of errtrace

Tags: bash, exception

I have better results with errtrace:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -Euxo
trap 'failure ${LINENO} "$BASH_COMMAND"' ERR

...dosomething

failure(){
  local lineno=$1
  local msg=$2
  report="Failed at $lineno: $msg"
  email_report
  exit 1
}

...bashscript continued
```

If I use set -e (errexit),

```
trap 'failure ${LINENO} "$BASH_COMMAND"' EXIT
```

My LINENO is always 1, where as with errtrace, it shows correct line number and I simply tell the script to exit inside the failure() function. So it seems like I get the same result, which is stop script execution when it catches an err and also reports correct line number where error happened.

Comment: I personally have never seen a reason for using `-e`, simply because I rarely have a shell script with the property that all commands need to deliver status 0. I think `-e` might help during debugging, for quickly running a script, say, via `bash -ex ....` but once you go so far as to actually write a `trap`, I don't think you will need `-e` anymore.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: @user1934428 I'm not sure I agree. In my team, ALL scripts must have '-e' (same way we require Perl/Javascript scripts to `use strict`). Running without a `-e` is like doing an `fopen` C call without checking the file pointer. In production, if something can go wrong, it will. Early exit is usually better than running a script with failed steps (which are usually bugs). From out experience, using '-e' will force us to consider error conditions, and we get higher quality scripts.

Comment: @user1934428 - if i just use -e, my script will fail and I would not know about it. if I trap it, I will be able to notify and email some useful information why it failed. I see as using trap and set -e or -E together. I don't want to try to predict everywhere my script should fail, I would rather put in exception where its ok for my script to fail and have it error out in all other (unforseen) cases.

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual of bash:

> **trap** [**-lp**] [[*arg*] *sigspec* ...]
>
> […]
>
> If a *sigspec* is **EXIT** (0) the command *arg* is executed on exit from the shell. If a *sigspec* is **DEBUG**, the command *arg* is executed before every *simple command*, *for* command, *case* command, *select* command, every arithmetic *for* command, and before the first command executes in a shell function (…). Refer to the description of the **extdebug** option to the **shopt** builtin for details of its effect on the **DEBUG** trap. If a *sigspec* is **RETURN**, the command *arg* is executed each time a shell function or a script executed with the **.** or **source** builtins finishes executing.
>
> If a *sigspec* is **ERR**, the command *arg* is executed whenever a simple command has a non-zero exit status, subject to the following conditions. The **ERR** trap is not executed if the failed command is part of the command list immediately following a **while** or **until** keyword, part of the test in an *if* statement, part of a command executed in a **&&** or **||** list, or if the command's return value is being inverted via **!**. These are the same conditions obeyed by the **errexit** option.
>
> Signals ignored upon entry to the shell cannot be trapped, reset or listed. Trapped signals that are not being ignored are reset to their original values in a subshell or subshell environment when one is created. The return status is false if any *sigspec* is invalid; otherwise **trap** returns true.

> **set -e**
>
> […] A trap on **ERR**, if set, is executed before the shell exits. This option applies to the shell environment and each subshell environment separately (…), and may cause subshells to exit before executing all the commands in the subshell.

> **exit** [n]
>
> […] A trap on **EXIT** is executed before the shell terminates.

Comment: so since my shell exited the trap executes, thus LINENO=1?